# Turning input into ASCII

Tags: java, ascii

I need to take ASCII characters between 32 and 93 and have them return a value of true, otherwise any other characters outside of those parameters would return a value of false.

```
public static boolean safeToUse(String plaintext) {  
    plaintext = plaintext.toUpperCase();  

        for (char i=1; plaintext.length(); i++);  
        (i >32 && i < 93);
        return true;    
        else return false;
}
```

Then I have another file that takes this code and spits out a true or false:

```
String plaintext;
    plaintext = "!";
    if (CryptoCode.safeToUse(plaintext)) {
        System.out.println("Yay, it's a valid message to crypt!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Ooops.");
    }
```

But the only return values i'm every getting is a return true regardless of if its false. And if I were to switch my "return true" value from the first code to a "return false" every answer would spit out a false value regardless of if it were true...

Comment: `safeToUse` makes no sense at all. What do you think you're supposed to be looping over?

Comment: Hint: 1) You probably want `String.charAt()`. 2) Calling `toUpperCase()` and ignoring the result is pointless. Note that strings are immutable.

Comment: Your for loop isn't even considering the `plaintext` parameter. You should read about Java - your looped always starts with `i == 1`, quitting immediately since it isn't in the 'safe' range

Comment: `for (char i=1; i>32 && i<93; i++);` what would you expect that to do?

Comment: I have no clue what it would do, this is my second week of class.. I'm working off of examples I've been shown and what I can find in the internet..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to convert to uppercase, but you can amend my example code below if you still need to do that.  Also I'm not sure from your statement if the filtering is meant to be including or excluding the edge values of 32 and 93.  I'll leave that for you to decide.

```
public static boolean safeToUse(String plaintext) {  

      for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++)
      {
           char c = plaintext.charAt(i);
           boolean valid = ( ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))  ||
                             ((c >= ' ') && (c <= ']')) );  // space is 32. right bracket is 93
           if (valid == false)
           {
               return false;
           }
      }

      return true;
}
```

Comment: `toUpperCase` is used to include lower case letters since only upper case letters are in this range http://www.asciitable.com/